# Close open section with jQuery toggle

Tags: jquery, togglebutton

I need help with my vertical menu. This is what I have right now:
http://jsfiddle.net/x4NbH/

What I want to do is if I have a `<ul>` open and click to open another section of the menu I want the open `<ul>` to close and the new one to open.
For example 'item-1' is open, I click 'item-2' and this closes 'item-1' and opens 'item-2'.

HTML:

```
<div class="menu-item">
<h4 id="item-1"><a href="#">Item 1</a></h4>
<ul id="item-1">
<li><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Link 2</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Link 3</a></li>
</ul>
</div>

<div class="menu-item">
<h4 id="item-2"><a href="#">Item 2</a></h4>
<ul id="item-2">
<li><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Link 2</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Link 3</a></li>
</ul>
</div>

<div class="menu-item">
<h4 id="item-3"><a href="#">Item 3</a></h4>
<ul id="item-3">
<li><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Link 2</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Link 3</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.menu-item h4 {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}
.menu-item ul {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px 5px;
    display: none;
}
```

JavaScript:

```
$( "h4#item-1" ).click(function() {
    $( "ul#item-1" ).toggle( "blind", 1000 );
});

$( "h4#item-2" ).click(function() {
    $( "ul#item-2" ).toggle( "blind", 1000 );
});

$( "h4#item-3" ).click(function() {
    $( "ul#item-3" ).toggle( "blind", 1000 );
});
```

How can I achieve this in a simple way?

Comment: IDs are supposed to be unique per page. Don't reuse the same ID on different elements.

Comment: Please always include the relevant code within the question.

Comment: @JakeGould yes it is, and it should be in the question.  SO is supposed to function independently from other sites.  If the rest of the internet disappeared, SO questions should still be useful for others who have a similar problem.  Links are useful but should not be required for a question to be useful to others.

Comment: @JosephSilber I know about reusing ID, but this was just a quick mock-up to show my problem. That's not what the question is about.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

IDs must be unique, you can use classes instead, try this:

```
var $ul = $('ul');
$( "h4" ).click(function() {
    $ul.hide("blind", 1000);
    $(this).next().show( "blind", 1000);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/zaZLj/

Comment: Actually, this worked great in fiddle, but stops working in html5boilerplate. Got any clue what it could be? I use the same jquery and jquery-ui releases as in the fiddle.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
$('h4').click(function(){
   $(this).closest('div').find('ul').show('blind',1000);
   $(this).closest('div').siblings().find('ul').hide('blind',1000);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

This is not as slick as the Nikko Reyes example above, but it works within the coding you provided to show the `complete` function used with toggle and the `.not()` jQuery command as well. I know I’ve done better but I just worked 8+ hours ;) The jsFiddle stuff is here: http://jsfiddle.net/jtMaY/17/

```
$( "h4#item-1" ).click(function() {
    $( "ul#item-1" ).toggle( "blind", 1000,
        function () { $( "ul" ).not("#item-1").hide(); }
    );
});

$( "h4#item-2" ).click(function() {
    $( "ul#item-2" ).toggle( "blind", 1000,
        function () { $( "ul" ).not("#item-2").hide(); }
    );
});

$( "h4#item-3" ).click(function() {
    $( "ul#item-3" ).toggle( "blind", 1000,
       function () { $( "ul" ).not("#item-3").hide(); }
    );
});
```